# Solve the equation: $x^2+\frac {1}{x^2}=2^{1-y^2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found the following problem interesting but do not know how to proceed:

> Solve the  equation:   $$x^2+\frac {1}{x^2}=2^{1-y^2}.$$

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: $x,y$ are real numbers or integers? Can they be negative ?

Comment: Hint: what is the smallest possible value of $x^2 + x^{-2}$ and what is the biggest possible value of $2^{1-y^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can proceed with the problem  in the following way:
We know that for any non-negative $a,b ; \quad a+b \geq 2 \sqrt {ab}$. So, $x^2 + \frac {1}{x^2} \geq 2 \sqrt {x^2. \frac {1}{x^2}}=2$. Hence the min. value of the left hand side of the equation is $2$. On the other hand ,the max. value of the 
right hand side is $2.$ So the given equation is equivalent to $x^2 + \frac {1}{x^2}=2$ and $2^{1-y^2}=2$.Hence solving the equations seperately,we get $x=\pm 1$ and $y=0.$

Comment: It'd be better if you also explain that $$ y^2 \ge 0\\ 1 - y^2 \le 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

The change of unknown $z=x^2$ transforms the equation into a quadratic equation for $z$.

Answer (score 0):

1. $x^2+\dfrac 1 {x^2}\ge2$ (By AM-GM inequality)
2. $2^{1-y^2}\le2$

Use this to solve your problem.